# SQL for calculating average from two different condition

Tags: timestamp, db2, conditional-statements, difference

Need to calculate the response time from when a call center rep receives lead and how long it takes for him to take followup

To calculate the time it takes For representative to see the 'NEW' lead AND 'Follow_up' on it

**TABLE T**

**ID**   ,    **T_NAME**   , **CRTE_TIMESTMP**

123     ,   NEW        ,     2019-01-01-00.15.32.2820000

456     ,   NEW         ,    2019-01-01-00.16.23.4320000

123     ,   FOLLOW-UP    ,   2019-01-02-15.31.48.1640000

****RESULT should be****

**ID**   ,     **TIME_TOOK**

123    ,   (2019-01-01-00.15.32.2820000) -(2019-01-02-15.31.48.1640000 )

Comment: Please show a reasonable attempt to solve the problem and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could look like this

```
with temp as (
select ID
     , T_NAME
     , CRTE_TIMESTMP,
       lag(CRTE_TIMESTMP) over (partition by id order by CRTE_TIMESTMP) as CRTE_TIMESTMP_lag
from t
) 
select ID
     , hours_between (CRTE_TIMESTMP,CRTE_TIMESTMP_lag ) as time_took
  from temp
 where t_name = 'FOLLOW-UP'
```

Depending on the granularity you need you could also use seconds_between or days_between or any of the other offered functions in Db2 11